# fix date and time on an news script

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli

Hello everyone i am just wondering if any one can tell me how can i fix my date and time please it comes as **Date** : `2018-08-09 06:09:20` : Time`

but i like it to be like   **Date** : `2018-08-09`  **Time** : `06:09:20`

if any one can help me that be Great

**main code**

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM news ORDER by title ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
echo "<center></br><u><h2>Title : " .$row['title']. "</h2></u>
  <strong>by</strong> <admin-css>" .$row['name']. "</admin-css></br> 
  <h3>" .$row['content']. "</h2>
  <u>Date : " .$row['timestamp']. "  : Time </u></br></br></center>"; 
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

[main database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Jsd.png)

[database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd3fA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by replacing the code line showing datetime to below one:

```
<u>Date : " .date('Y-m-d' , strtotime($row['timestamp'])). "  : Time : " .date('H:i:sA' , strtotime($row['timestamp'])). "</u></br></br></center>";
```

Or you can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` in your query as:

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`) AS unix_timestamp FROM news ORDER by title;
```

And in code it can be used as:

```
<u>Date : " .date('Y-m-d' , $row['timestamp']). "  : Time : " .date('H:i:sA' , $row['timestamp']). "</u></br></br></center>";
```

Comment: thanks Sinto the first one showed me not the right time but it worked in the end
the other one it gave me an blank page as error

Comment: ok, fine. You have to keep the time values in db in UTC. otherwise while using `date()` it will convert to a time which is set in our project.

Answer (score 0):

Just use explode function after query from database and break your timestamp string like below:

```
$str = "2018-08-09 06:09:20";
$splitString = explode(" ",$str);
echo "Date: ".$splitString[0];
echo "<br>";
echo "Time: ".$splitString[1];
```

**Output will be:**

```
Date: 2018-08-09
Time: 06:09:20
```

**Replace you code with below code:**

```
$splitString = explode(" ",$row['timestamp']);
echo "<center></br><u><h2>Title : " .$row['title']. "</h2></u>
  <strong>by</strong> <admin-css>" .$row['name']. "</admin-css></br> 
  <h3>" .$row['content']. "</h2>
  <u>Date : " .$splitString[0]. "  : Time: </u></br></br>" .$splitString[1]. "</center>";
```

Hope it help you, try and let me know if required any help.

Comment: i am looking to do it from database not in code thanks anyway

Comment: Yes you can follow above answer for database, both ways you can ...depends on you but best and fast if you prefer from database.